# Why is this basic Meteor create project command failing?

Tags: javascript, meteor, windows-7, command-prompt, wsh

At the Windows 7 command prompt, I entered "meteor create blogtest" which should create a Meteor project.

I get, though, a Windows Script Host MS JScript runtime error, namely Code 800A1391, "*'tern' is undefined*" (at line 6, char 3)

Script file implicated is C:\Misc\meteor.js

Subsequently trying "meteor update" gives me the same err msg.

WTH (What The Hec Ramsey)?

### UPDATE

Meanwhile, back at the command prompt (after changing the name of the file in C:\Misc from "meteor.js" to "meteor.jsold"), I tried "meteor update" again, just to make sure it would give me a "who or what the heck is meteor?" type of msg.

Instead, it cogitated a good while, tapping its forehead and humming softly to itself, and finally offered:

*C:\Misc>meteor update
The latest version of Meteor, 1.2.0.2, is already installed on this
computer. Run 'meteor update' inside of a particular project directory to
update that project to Meteor 1.2.0.2*

So then I said to myself, "*Self, why not try the 'meteor create blogtest' again to see what happens?*"

I did; it worked; the project was created and is now running at localhost 3000.

???

Comment: Do you know where the meteor installation files are located in windows? Maybe you could try removing them and installing meteor from scratch.

Comment: Yes, the err msg says where it is (C:\Misc); and it is there, 74KB. I don't know "what all" is installed, so don't know if deleting meteor.js and starting over would be enough, but I'll try it - what the Hey, hey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Unix-based systems (Linux/OS X) `meteor` itself is a shell script (same thing as a Windows batch file). It handles downloading Meteor if it does not exist, then running the main JS file. I presume things work the same way on Windows.

Comment: Okay...but that doesn't explain (does it?) why it failed until I renamed meteor.js